# Get tfoot th value by ID using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

Look at the following:

```
<table border="0" id="npoGridView">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Quantity Order</th>
                    <th>Cost P.U</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                   //TD .......      
            </tbody>
               <tfoot>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Quantity Order</th>
                    <th>Cost P.U</th>
                    <th id="15">Total</th>
                  </tr>
              </tfoot>
        </table>
```

I have given id to **th** in **tfoot** (i.e. id="15"), Now I want to get **th** value using jquery.

How to get the specific **th** value form footer using jquery?

Comment: [HTML attribute values can't start with digits](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/values.html)

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#npoGridView tfoot').each(function() {
  console.log($('th', this).text());
});
```

To get the value of any specific `th` like `<th id="15">Total</th>`;

```
$('tfoot th#15').text();
```

you can get the value of `th` like following:

```
$('tfoot th:eq(0)').text(); // output: Quantity Order

$('tfoot th:eq(1)').text(); // output: Cost P.U

$('tfoot th:eq(2)').text(); // output: Total
```

You could use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text) or [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html) as you need.

To update value of `th` then use:

```
$('tfoot th#15').html($grandTotal);
```

or

```
$('tfoot th#15').text($grandTotal);
```

**NOTE** Don't use only numeric value as `id` .

Comment: value get successfylly! $('tfoot th#15').html(''+$grandTotal+''); appending the value, not overwriting. How can I overwrite old value?

Answer (score 2):

$(th_id).text()
This will give the text value present with that particular dom element

Comment: value get successfylly! $('tfoot th#15').html(''+$grandTotal+''); appending the value, not overwriting. How can I overwrite old value? @Sanket

Answer (score 1):

I would use .html()...

```
$('th#15').html();
```

Also, keep in mind that an ID should not be/begin with a number.

Comment: value get successfylly! $('tfoot th#15').html(''+$grandTotal+''); appending the value, not overwriting. How can I overwrite old value?

Comment: Why are you using $('tfoot th#15').html(''+$grandTotal+'');? $('tfoot th#15').html($grandTotal); should do it...